# How to detect Ctrl+1 key press in TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, keypress

I tried to detect ctrl + 1 key press in textbox on WinForm but the following code is not detecting the ctrl key press. Any suggestion will be helpful.

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if ((ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.D1)
            MessageBox.Show("1 get selected");
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if do an `&&` of two enum values?

Comment: @Meehow could you please explain? Helpful if you give a sample.

Comment: `if (Keys.Control && Keys.D1)`? *just make sure it's the right number 1, as you're using the NumPad's1 but in the title you mention just the `1`

Comment: The KeyDown event does not have a KeyPressEventArgs argument.  Use the KeyDown event, not KeyPressed.

Comment: @amaneureka If I knew or understand that this is duplicate question would I asked.

Comment: @ThePiranha: It's completely alright, I mentioned "duplicate" for other who  seek to this question while finding a solution for their problem. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `(ModifierKeys & Keys.Control)` is what's causing your trouble. I'd suggest to keep it simple :

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.D1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Selected !");
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn it... you beat me by a split second ^^

Comment: Thanks @Mekap. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion but it might be because of you comparing KeyChar instead of KeyCode.
Try

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.D1)
        {
                MessageBox.Show("1 get selected");
        }
}
```